# Removing and adding event handlers for different ComboBoxes where the ComboBox is passed as a parameter

Tags: vb.net, event-handling

I have a method that takes a ComboBox as a parameter and then adds data to it. When data is added, the SelectedIndexChangedEvent fires. Is there a way that, in the called method, I can remove the above event handler for whatever ComboBox is passed as a parameter and then add is at the end of the method? I know how to remove and add specific handlers, but can't figure out how to do it based on which ComboBox is passed.

Here's the method..

```
Private Sub PopulateComboBox(ByRef cboBox As ComboBox, ByVal itemSource As String)
    'Remove handler for cboBox
    'Do stuff that would otherwise cause the event handler to execute
    'Add handler for cboBox
End Sub
```

I have 4 ComboBoxes - would it just be easier to remove all 4 event handlers and then add them again at the end of the code? I would however like to know if this is possible so that I can possibly apply to re-usable code in the future

Comment: how does using the `cboBox` var passed not work?

Comment: Passing the combo box works fine. I just need to remove the event handler for whichever combobox is passed and for that I need somehow to pass the event handler method as well. The event handler method is a different method for each combobox

Comment: `_SelectedItemChangedEvent ` is this WinForms?  Do you mean `SelectedIndexChanged`?

Comment: Ah. yes. typo edited - tho i did mean SelectedIndexChanged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic way to go about this is to do this:

```
Private Sub PopulateComboBox(ByRef cboBox As ComboBox, ByVal itemSource As String)
    RemoveHandler cboBox.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged
    'Do stuff that would otherwise cause the event handler to execute
    AddHandler cboBox.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub
```

Another option, which might be better in some circumstances, is to do this:

```
Private _ignoreComboBox As ComboBox = Nothing

Private Sub PopulateComboBox(ByRef cboBox As ComboBox, ByVal itemSource As String)
    _ignoreComboBox = cboBox
    'Do stuff that would otherwise cause the event handler to execute
    _ignoreComboBox = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If sender Is Not _ignoreComboBox Then

    End If
End Sub
```

Or, to handle multiple combo boxes at the same time:

```
Private _ignoreComboBoxes As List(Of ComboBox) = New List(Of ComboBox)()

Private Sub PopulateComboBox(ByRef cboBox As ComboBox, ByVal itemSource As String)
    _ignoreComboBoxes.Add(cboBox)
    'Do stuff that would otherwise cause the event handler to execute
    _ignoreComboBoxes.Remove(cboBox)
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If Not _ignoreComboBoxes.Contains(DirectCast(sender, ComboBox)) Then

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Plutonix and Enigmativity - Thanks both of you for very helpful answers - I have no idea as to which to choose as the definitive answer though. I realize this may count as chatty, but do either of you have a preference for  an answer?

Comment: @DavidWilson - Truly up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
' these happen to map to the same event handler
Private cb1Event As EventHandler = AddressOf cbx_SelectedIndexChanged
Private cb2Event As EventHandler = AddressOf cbx_SelectedIndexChanged
```

Then when used:

```
PopulateComboBox(cb1, items, cb1Event)
PopulateComboBox(cb2, items, cb2Event) 
' or
PopulateComboBox(cb3, items, AddressOf cbx_SelectedIndexChanged)
```

The method would be declared:

```
Private Sub PopulateComboBox(cboBox As ComboBox, 
                            items As String, ev As EventHandler)
```

Personally, since you know the cbo involved anyway, I'd do that before the call:

```
RemoveHandler cb1.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf cbx_SelectedIndexChanged
PopulateComboBox(cb1, items)
AddHandler cb1.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf cbx_SelectedIndexChanged
```

There is not much to be gained by passing all the info to do something to something else so it can do what you know needs to be done.

Comment: @DavidWilson FYI you dont get pinged by `@xxx` unless you have a comment on that post.  The best/preferred depends on the situation.  In this case, a bool ignore flag would be simpler - that is just not what you asked for. If the controls have some dependency - changing cb1 does something to cb2 - you can make the bool "smarter" so that method 3 doesnt undo method 1's setting prematurely.

Comment: Thanks for your help,  but Enigmativity's last solution gels better with me as I think I'll find it easier to incorporate into other programs.